# Remove error suppress operator

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a code like this :

```
foreach ($this->dayCounts as $activity => $day) {
    foreach ($day as $date => $columns) {
        foreach ($columns as $column => $value) {
            @$this->totalCounts[$activity][$column] += $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically it is adding daily values for each activity and each column to get total counts. I am using `'@'` operator here not to throw the warning. Is there any modification that I can make which will remove the `'@'` operator as it is not a good practice to use it.

The error I am getting is `Undefined index` with the column and activity name.

Comment: Why are you suppressing? Use `try...catch`  for such erroneous code.

Comment: @Parixit accessing undefined index won't result in exception being thrown so try/catch won't help

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I know. I mean if we write neat and clean code then it's really hard to have any warning/notice. Yes, `try...catch` is not to suppress it, instead it will suppress exceptions only.

Answer (score 0):

Warnings you're supressing might be caused by non-existent indexes in **$this->totalCounts** array. You can avoid them by explicitely initializing fields of this array.

Replace

```
@$this->totalCounts[$activity][$column] += $value;
```

with

```
if (!isset($this->totalCounts[$activity][$column])) {
  $this->totalCounts[$activity][$column] = 0;
}
$this->totalCounts[$activity] += $value;
```